# How can we return the user details along with token in Django rest framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am using the [drf_jwt_2fa](https://github.com/suutari/drf-jwt-2fa) package for 2-factor authentication in Django.

I want to get the user details when the second-time user passes the code and token.

Right now when the user calls `obtain_auth_token` it's only returning the JWT for the further API call.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user details inside any view using request.user

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_current_user(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = request.user
        serializer = UserDataSerializer(user)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

I've made a simple endpoint only for that:

```
url(r'^currentuser/$', views.get_current_user)
```

So on your front-end you need to call the endpoint to get the user details.

Comment: Zoro thanks for your response, but i need to minimise the number of request to get user details , as now for the package drf_jwt_2fa we have to make 2 request to validate user and  get the detials
First request : User send user name and passowrd and server send token and OTP.
OTP is send to the email
Second request: In the second request user send OTP with the token
If valid user will get the JWT
3rd request: In the 3rd user need to make another request to get the user details